# How to clear the last -10 info?

Tags: linux, users, logs, privacy

How to clear the last -10 information only for a Linux system? I tried to execute the command `> /var/log/wtmp` to clear the last info, but it clears the whole login info , but I need to clear only last -10 login info.

Comment: What are you some kind of evil H4xx0r?  Why would you want to clear out the logs that are there for security auditing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wtmp file is a sequence of `struct utmp` records.  To remove the last 10 records, you first discover the size of a utmp record, then you truncate the wtmp file to its current size minus the ten times the size of a utmp record.

A simple C program will give you the size of a utmp record.

```
#include <utmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct utmp foo;

main()
{
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof foo);
    return 0;
}
```

and a Perl script will truncate the wtmp file

```
$utmp_size = utmp_record_size_goes_here;
$wtmp_file = "wtmp filename goes here";
open WTMP, "+<", $wtmp_file or die "$wtmp_file: ", $!;
seek WTMP, -10 * $utmp_size, 2;
truncate WTMP, tell(WTMP);
close WTMP;
```

Comment: @Mughil: Kyle has presented the "not-so-simple" part, and it works quite nicely (on a test text file).  What is it that isn't simple enough? Perhaps it is compiling the `c` program? That requires `utmpc=~/bin/utmpsize.c; gcc -o "${utmpc%.c}" "$utmpc" 2>/dev/null && chmod +x "${utmpc%.c}"`... then you just fill in the *"goes_here"* parts of the first 2 lines of the perl script, add a hash-bang header, eg: `#!/usr/bin/perl`,  then make it executable via: `chmod +x perl-script-name` and just run the perl script. You could alternatively use `truncate`, but that needs the file *and* struct sizes.

Comment: @Peter `truncate` accepts negative size increments, so it is enough to know only `sizeof(struct utmp)`.